# css3 transitions: fluid layout animations on floating items

Tags: html, css, animation, layout, css-transitions

I would like to archieve something like fluid layout transitions in Silverlight, or like seen in the new css transition powered photolist view in skydrive. I thought this could be done using CSS3 somehow.

assuming I have something like this:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        3
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .item {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Where item could be some square or an image or anything.
Now we have a floated list of items, that wraps the items when getting resized.
What I'd like to achieve is getting those items to animate fluently, when they're getting wrapped to the next row, or float away to make place for an newly added item in between.

This could probably done with some javascript magic using absolute positioning, but then you'll sacrifice css layouting and have to do everything manually.

Is there any way to say something like `transition: left, top 1s ease-in-out;`?

I tried wrapping the item inside some parent div, that is floated, while the item itself has absolute positioning, but then the position is relative to its parent, so no transition there.

[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Rich-Interactions-Using-Blend-4-Transition-Effects-Fluid-Layout-and-Layout-States-Silverlig/) is a video from channel9 that shows several effects, I was talking about the one thats showing up around 1:20.

Comment: Can you post a link to a demo of the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: isotope is pretty much what I was looking for: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery** does exactly that.  But back up for a second.

*I'm blurried eyed and need so sleep, so I apologize if this is only half coherent, but maybe it'll tip you in the right direction.*

First it's important to consider the right tool for the job.  CSS3 is awesome, but not very backwards compatible, so you'd be depending on javascript for older browsers anyway.  If you do want to go for it, Nuttuts is always a great resource, and here's an [article on CSS3](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/):

Without a doubt, I would suggest jQuery (a library of javascript). You don't have to use absolute positioning, and it's all about your specific goal.  You'd have to post that to get more specific advice.  Animate() is a good all purpose function, along with Fadin(), fadeout(), which should serve that exact need.  Search for examples, and you should find what you're looking for.

There's premade scripts and tools for just about everything you can imagine, I'd google for scripts/plugins for exactly what you're looking for.  Chances are, it's out there.  That's a pretty popular need as well, at least that general concept.

Good luck!  (if you're having trouble, send more specifics of the exact goal/function, and if you have it, the site as it is currently)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jquery would still need me to calculate the items positions and stuff manually, not being able to use css layouting(maybe trough some hacky way). But it seems the only way currently, and theres a very nice JQuery plugin out there called Isotope (see link above), which does it manually but pretty nice. Using css3 for the animations would be nice as it would be completely ok if some animations don't show up in older browsers. Thanks anyway